# DirectShow SNDDEVInError device error

Tags: directshow

Sometimes when invoking *"IMediaControl::Run"* a SNDDEVInError error occurs with the output prameters 1 and 4.
According to msdn the first parameter (1) means error in opening the device (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377614(v=vs.85).aspx). For the second parameter I have no idea what the meaning of the second parameter is. 
Can somebody tell why this error happens?
Besides, it seams that the sound input device randomly disconnects, regardless if it is an internal soundcard or a USB acquisition sound card.

Comment: How do you know it's `SNDDEV_ERR` error?

Comment: Retrieving the events notification (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377538(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: OK, so it's `EC_SNDDEV_IN_ERROR` and `SNDDEV_ERROR_Open`. Pretty much unusual error but if it's what you get then it's something with interfacing to legacy audio input device. It might be in use or reports specific format as supported and fails to actually use it. Or it's improperly installed. It's just guessing from the data you provided so far.

Comment: I'm using DirectShowLib but I think it doesn't matter.

To add the audio capture filter in the filter graph I'm using this code (nothing else):  

    DsDevice[] devices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.AudioInputDevice);  
    DsDevice device = devices[0];  

    Guid iid = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;  
    device.Mon.BindToObject(null, null, ref iid, out source);  

    IBaseFilter audioSourceFilter = (IBaseFilter) source;  
    hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(audioSourceFilter, "Audio Capture");  

Am missing something? For example IAMStreamConfig or IAMAudioInputMixer.

Comment: The code is about right. You need to make sure the device is at all properly working in tools like GraphEdit and GraphEditNext. If it does not work there (esp. with similar symptoms) then it's a driver issue. Also this tools let you discover interactively options you will also have programmatically.

Comment: This issue occurs randomly, sporadically and on several and different machines. 
Not only I used GraphEdit and GraphEditNext, but I, also, made a tool to reproduce that error, but nothing happened. 
Maybe this error is misleading me, and the real problem is another one.